# How do I order associated objects with searchlogic in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, searchlogic

Hello again great knowledge masters of stackoverflow,
once again the small coder apprentice tabaluga is in need of help

The Goal : make the username sortable in the view. The difficulty is, that I am Querying Profiles in the controller ( Profile.username doesn't exist but Profile.user.username does). How Do I accomplish that? My Code so far

model code

```
Class User < Activerecord::Base
   attr_accessible :username
   has_one :profile
 end

 Class Profile < Activerecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
 end
```

controller code

```
@search = Profile.search(params[:search])
```

view code

```
<%= order @search, :by => :user_username %>
```

okay, the view code doesn't work (obviously) how can I pass the associated object in the view code and convert it to a symbol?

Thanks in advance :)

p.s. EDIT I just figured out, that this code actually works, sorry for bothering :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating a `named_scope` in your `Profile` model which sorts the profiles by user before feeding into your search. Something like:

```
named_scope :sorted_by_user, { :include => :user, :conditions => ["ORDER BY user.username"] }
```

Then

```
@search = Profile.sorted_by_user.search(params[:search])
```

Comment: thanks bjg, the problem with this approach is, that you cannot use the order method in the view, because the order is hardcoded in the named_scope.

Comment: @tabaluga OK I see what you're trying to do. The `:by` option just creates some additional GET parameters that the `search` method processes. You pre-parse the `params` in your controller and then call the appropriate `search` variant, with or without the named scope as required.